# Value of an NSManagedObject's property newly created at every get?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

Consider the following code

```
NSManagedObject *o = ... ;

o.myProperty = [NSDate date];

NSDate *a = o.myProperty;
NSDate *b = o.myProperty;

BOOL identical = (a==b);
BOOL equal = [a isEqual:b];
```

running this on my iPhone with iOS 5 sets `identical = NO` and `equal = YES`

Is this expected behavior? I would have thought that reading a property returns always the same object and doesn't create a new one everytime the getter is called.

Or is this a bug in iOS?

Comment: NSLog with the %p format and you'll see why.

Comment: sure, I know that `a` and `b` point to different objects. I am just wondering why this is, since I'm reading the same property from the managed object.

Comment: == is comparing the pointers, not what they point to.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are comparing objects then always use equalObjects: rather than just using == comparison operator. By the way, you should use compare: method in this case to compare to dates if they are the same. In your context, you should use it like this,

```
[a compare:b] == NSOrderedSame // both the date are same, whatever the object br
```